# how to use external plugins in Angular project

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am converting my jquery based project to angular..
How should i go about using plugins

1.Should I replace old Jquery plugins with angular plugins

2.Or should I integrate them using controllers/directives

Comment: use angular plugin for same plugin which you are using for jquery

Comment: could you please explain

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a angular webapp and faced this same question. 
For mostly of the jQuery plugins there angular wrappers that encapsulate the jQuery plugin. This turns code cleanner and you don't have to handle with compatibility issues yourself.
I suggest you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just include libraries in main/index.html.

and in controller
instead of this

> $(document).ready(function(){
>      // jQuery methods go here
>       });

use

> angular.element(document).ready(function(){
>      // jQuery methods go here
>       });

in the respective controllers.

it will work fine

Comment: m adding a custom html element using directive..so how do the same using directives?

Comment: you can use custom directives for this.

http://embed.plnkr.co/gnuo7LXwshKl9tVgEQAe/

.

https://plnkr.co/edit/pvPcaMHzFgoCQrmw2vKQ?p=preview
.

for further you can refer.
 https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive